# how to store video files in byte form

Tags: android, video-streaming

I would like to store the bytes of a video file in a datastore somewhere. I have tried storing them in sqlite but the file is too big. what other alternative is there. I want also o be able to search fro that byte array given the name of the video file.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend that you store it as a file and use database to only store metadata and reference to that file (filename and path for example). That will allow you to search for any metadata using DB without dumping tons of binary content into database.

Comment: The idea is, i would like to hide videos hence delete them from the sdcard but at the same time having a backup in from of bytes so that if the user wants to unhide the video, the program writes to an outputstream using the stored bytes.

Comment: If you want to keep full backup on device (which,depending on size of videos seems like a waste of space), you can always write them to your app private area in addition to SD card.